# jquery slide out div from right

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to achieve a "slide out from right" effect on a div using jquery. I am able to achieve it partially, but not how I need it. I have setup a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BUSKw/1/).

The div nicely slides out, but the text inside it wraps when toggling. Is there a way to prevent the text from wrapping? I went through other SO posts, but couldn't find a solution. I would request you to put up an example if possible.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would you want it to do instead?

Comment: I would want it not to wrap the text while toggling in and out. Instead, just slide in and out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it using css. You can look at the fix here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yJYRZ/4/

You could obviously make this more specific by saying #home p, for example. That's your call.